# Cannot connect to MySQL with MySQLdb in Python, can connect from command line

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having trouble connecting to my local MySQL database in python, but have no problem connecting from the command line.

When I try this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="username",    
                     passwd="password",
                     db="dbname",
                     port=3306,
                     unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock")
```

I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I get the same error when I don't explicitly pass in the socket path.  I get a similar error when I use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` as the host (also removing the unix socket argument):

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

I know that MySQL is running, as when I can connect to the database from the command line no problem with `mysql -u username -p dbname`.  I also know MySQL is listening on `127.0.0.1`, when I run `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p` I can connect as well.  I'm also sure it's listening on port `3306`.

Comment: Hello Evan ! I know this may be obvious but have you tried restarting your mysql. 'sudo service mysql restart'

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Many times ;)

Comment: My next suggestion would be to completely uninstall and reinstall it

Comment: I would also check how much memory is left. I ran into the same problem by not having enough disk space.

Comment: Not seeing anything taking up much memory... Tried running the connection code in python with `top` open and didn't see anything spike.  Also I would consider doing the reinstall, but I literally just installed mysql on this machine yesterday so it's hard for me to imagine that would change anything.